# How do I drag a formula across columns, changing the cell reference only automatically?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am adding together totals from multiple google sheets to a master sheet.

How can I drag across the following formula into adjacent cells, changing only the cell reference: from `b7` to `c7`, `d7` and so forth?

Please help :(

When I drag across, it only duplicates the same formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bABp9VIhCteTADU5L-ueJptF8YcrLhhhQGQM5LZOnpU/edit#gid=1548862584","b7")+IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y-C1WhOdzOw4C0PUbiI0ZDKBC4CeRCR6z66jLc_yRSo/edit#gid=1548862584","b7")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cells you're working with are in the same relative position try something like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bABp9VIhCteTADU5L-ueJptF8YcrLhhhQGQM5LZOnpU/edit#gid=1548862584",ADDRESS(ROW(B7),COLUMN(B7)))+IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y-C1WhOdzOw4C0PUbiI0ZDKBC4CeRCR6z66jLc_yRSo/edit#gid=1548862584",ADDRESS(ROW(B7),COLUMN(B7)))
```